# What properties do the solutions of linear difference equations have?

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

If I remember correctly, a solution to a linear difference equation is another equation parameterized by some values. Therefore isn't it true that for a linear difference equation $g(p) = xg(p - 1) + yg(p + 1)$, where x and y are nonzero, any scalar multiple of its solution is also a solution? How about the product and/or sums of its solutions? Are they not also solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(p)=xg(p - 1) + yg(p + 1)$$

For any $\lambda,\mu$ such that $\lambda^2+\mu^2\ne 0$, we trivially verify that $\lambda g(n)+\mu g(n)$ is also a solution. Indeed
$$\lambda g(n)+\mu g(n)=\lambda\left(xg(p - 1) + yg(p + 1)\right)+\mu\left(xg(p - 1) + yg(p + 1)\right)=\\=(\lambda+\mu)x g(p-1)+(\lambda+\mu)y g(p+1)=x'g(p-1)+y'g(p+1)$$

Hope this can help

**Bonus**: I calculated the general solution, but it was useless for the proof:
$$g(n)=a \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 x y}}{2 y}\right)^p+b \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-4 x y}+1}{2 y}\right)^p$$

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need for the arbitrary condition that $\lambda^2+\mu^2\ne0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt OP says that $x,y$ are nonzero. $g(p)=0$ sucks as  solution...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to say?